# absolute position on child is hidden in the fixed sidepanel

Tags: css, css-position, tailwind-css

I am working with dashboard with TailwindCSS framework, that has fixed (CSS position) top panel, fixed (CSS position) sidepanel and absolute (CSS position) main content. I have a tooltip in side panel, whose hover-effect is hidden within the side panel.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="fixed z-10 h-10 w-full bg-red-500">Top Panel</div>

<div class="h-screen">
  <div class="fixed top-10 z-10 h-full w-3/12 overflow-y-auto border-r-4 border-blue-500 bg-gray-100 pb-64">
    Sidepanel
    <p class="relative flex items-center text-sm font-light text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
      <button data-popover-placement="bottom-end" type="button"><svg class="w-5 h-5 ml-2 text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500" aria-hidden="true" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 10a8 8 0 11-16 0 8 8 0 0116 0zm-8-3a1 1 0 00-.867.5 1 1 0 11-1.731-1A3 3 0 0113 8a3.001 3.001 0 01-2 2.83V11a1 1 0 11-2 0v-1a1 1 0 011-1 1 1 0 100-2zm0 8a1 1 0 100-2 1 1 0 000 2z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></button></p>
    <div data-popover role="tooltip" class="absolute z-50 w-72 rounded-lg border border-gray-200 bg-white text-sm font-light text-gray-500 shadow-sm transition-opacity duration-300 dark:border-gray-600 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400">
      <div class="space-y-2 p-3">
        <p>This is the content of helper tooltip. Testing if the help is completely visible or not. Unfortunately not displaying the help.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="absolute top-10 left-1/4 z-0 min-h-full w-9/12 overflow-y-auto">Main content</div>
</div>
```

Please note that, I do not reproduce javascript part, as i have issue only with CSS part. In my application, when mouse enters the question mark, the helper text will appear. Currently, the helper text (below the question mark) is visible up to sidepanel width, and hidden beyond that. I want this helper text to be visible above the sidepanel and maincontent (Like the content of higher z-index value).

Thanks in advance for the help. If any further information required, please let me know.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake, I have modified the question now appropriately. I will follow the procedure for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is that the side panel (fixed position) is preventing any overflow. It works if you add `overflow: visible` to the side panel.

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for the time to answer. I just tested your solution, but I am sorry, that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: [Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/x6t5epvf/) showing what I was referring to.

Comment: Hello Chad, I really appreciate your effort. When I apply overflow: visible, the scroll bar auto along the y-axis is gone for the side panel (which is important for me to have scroll bar on y-axis). And when I try to apply "overflow-x: visible", scrollbar for y-axis exists but again the problem remains unsolved (I do not understand the reason). 

Please guide me if you have some corrections for this. Thanks again for your help and efforts.